# QueryExtender with dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

i am using QueryExtender with dropdownlist to filter gridview ( datasource : EntityDataSource).

```
  <asp:SearchExpression SearchType="StartsWith" DataFields="Status" >
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStatus" Type="String"   />
  </asp:SearchExpression>
```

Where i bind my ddlStatus from database with default value : "Select"
But when i run project it takes by default value "Select" for Field "status" and gives empty grid.
But on Pageload i want to show all the records after user can select different status from dropdownlist and based on that filter should work.

how can we show all the data with dropdownlist value selected as default "select"

Comment: Can you make your `Select` item like this
 `<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />` ?

Comment: Yes i can make like you suggested. but no result. blank grid

Comment: show your page_load code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Found solution here in book: [Entity Framework 4.0 Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wB3ACQzTeRAC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=query%20extender%20with%20dropdownlist&source=bl&ots=flfZHz_ZBx&sig=WI-lQzZ5RL5bPkCVWRwNKTCeGN4&hl=en&ei=nwFVTprkB8qCOsCi-aQG&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Used PropertyExpression instead of SearchExpression

```
<asp:PropertyExpression>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStatus" Type="String"   />
</asp:PropertyExpression>
```

and leave value blank according to [Bala R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273200/bala-r) comment

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.defaultvalue.aspx) like this

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select" />
```

and

```
<asp:SearchExpression SearchType="StartsWith" DataFields="Status" >
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStatus" Type="String" Default="Select"  />
 </asp:SearchExpression>
```